# How to export a TestNG suite to jar file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jar, testng, executable-jar, testng-eclipse

I'm new to Selenium I have exported TestNG suite to jar file using the Eclipse export option but am unable to run it.

Comment: You need to specify the main class. Like this:
java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycomp.myproj.AnotherClassWithMainMethod Or you can create a manifest fifle to create a runnable jar

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to run a jar file you need to have a class with main method pointed to your `Launch configuration` while exporting.

you can run TestNG programmatically by creating this main method,

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}
```

Add this main method class to your `Launch Configuration` while exporting the jar in eclipse.

Refer this testNG doc for more information : [Run testNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)

If you are using `maven-jar-plugin` to export jar make sure you have added your `mainClass` in `manifest`.